# Express - REST API - repository instance is lost during routing

Tags: node.js, express, typescript, routes, repository

please can you help me with my routing problem? I'm trying to make a REST API using typescript and repository pattern in Node.js (express).

I have two generic classes **BaseRepository** and **BaseController** which together handle the basic CRUD transactions. Other domain controllers are derived from these ones.

There is my code:

**productRouter.ts** used to handle routes:

```js
import { Router } from 'express';

import { ProductController } from '../controllers/ProductController';

class ProductRouter {
    private _router: Router;
    private _controller: ProductController;

    constructor() {
        this._router = Router();
        this._controller = new ProductController;
    }

    get routes(): Router {
        this._router.get('/product', this._controller.getAll);
        this._router.post('/product', this._controller.create);
        this._router.get('/product/:id', this._controller.getById);
        this._router.put('/product/:id', this._controller.update);
        this._router.delete('/product/:id', this._controller.delete);
        return this._router;
    }
}
```

**productController.ts** used to init the BaseRepository and its derived from the BaseController.

```js
import { BaseController } from '../common/BaseController';
import { BaseRepository, IRepository } from '../common/BaseRepository';

import { Product, IProduct } from '../models/Product';

export class ProductController extends BaseController<IProduct> {

    constructor() {
        const productRepository = new BaseRepository<IProduct>(Product);
        super(productRepository);
    }
}
```

**BaseController.ts**

```js
export class BaseController<T> implements IController {
    private _repository: IRepository<T>;

    constructor(repository: IRepository<T>) {
        this._repository = repository;
    }
    getAll(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): void {
        this._repository.getAll((err, result) => {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json(result);
        });
    }
```

Every time I navigate to appropriate route I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_repository' of undefined
    at BaseController.getAll (C:\Users\vrbat\Documents\Projects\router-test\src\api\common\BaseController.ts:19:13)
    enter code here
```

I don't know why, because the _repository property is iniciated in productController.ts.

Comment: Which line is 19th line in your BaseController.ts. According to error message we need to see 19th line.

Comment: 19th line is a place where this._repository.getAll function is called.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging I figured out that the problem is in the wrong scoping of *_repository* property.

The following code will fix it:

productRouter.ts

```js
get routes(): Router {
        this._router.get('/product', this._controller.getAll());
        this._router.post('/product', this._controller.create());
        this._router.get('/product/:id', this._controller.getById());
        this._router.put('/product/:id', this._controller.update());
        this._router.delete('/product/:id', this._controller.delete());
        return this._router;
    }
```

BaseController.ts

```js
export class BaseController<T> implements IController {
    private _repository: IRepository<T>;

    constructor(repository: IRepository<T>) {
        this._repository = repository;
    }
    getAll() {
        const repository = this._repository;
        return (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
            repository.getAll((err, result) => {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);

                res.json(result);
            });
        };
    }
```